# Calling PHP within PHP to grab category link

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Im no guru at Wordpress, but this one is doing my head in.

I am using a category image which appears next to my post title.  I want to link that category image to the actual category itself.  I have tried many different ways and I just cant get it to work.  Currently, the link is returning the domain URL alone (ie http://example.com).

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );
$category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
?>
foreach ( $categories as $category ) { 
echo '<div class="row">
<div class="column left"><a href="' . esc_url( $get_category_link ) . '">
<img src="' . esc_url( 'http://example.com/icons/' . intval( $category->term_id ) . '.png' ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $category->name ) . '" /></div>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: What is `$get_category_link` supposed to be?

Comment: ^ this, you are setting `$category_link` but using `$get_category_link` which appears to be nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't do what you want. Use something like this:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
echo '<div class="row">';
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<div class="column left"><a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category ) ) . '">
<img src="' . esc_url( 'http://example.com/icons/' . intval( $category->term_id ) . '.png' ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $category->name ) . '" /></div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

This is very similar to Alive to Die's answer except I didn't use additional variables in foreach loop and extracted '' outside the loop (and added closing div after the loop).

PS: I use `get_the_category` as in the question, because I assume it is used for current post in WordPress Loop. If it is not, `get_categories` would do.